# Batch how to read a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io

I need to make a batch file that can read a text file and I am using windows 7 ultimate 32 bit

I am currently using this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%x in (test.txt) do set "Var=%%x"
ECHO %Var%
pause
```

But this only reads the first line and I need it to read the whole thing. I need it to display the full text file.

Comment: Well, it reads all the file, but since you are overwritting the variable value, at end it only holds the last line of file. Please, edit question to reflect what is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to read the text file *and do what* with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type test.txt') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!
)
pause
```

You need to enclose the `for` loop with brackets if you are performing multiple commands inside the `for` loop. Besides that, `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` will helps to [expand the variable at execution time rather than at parse time](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this should read the whole file and set `Var` to the *last* line.

If you need to process the whole file, you have several options:

1. If you just need to do something for every line, then just use a block instead of the `set "Var=%%x"`:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%x in (test.txt) do (
     rem Do something with %%x
   )
   ```
2. If you need the complete file line-by-line in memory, use a counter and emulate arrays with lots of variables:

   ```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set cnt=0
   for /f "delims=" %%x in (test.txt) do (
     set "ine[!cnt!]=%%x"
     set /a cnt+=1
   )
   set /a numlines=cnt-1
   ```

   and afterwards you can just use a `for /l` loop to access them again.